# Fast drawing/rendering 2d image texture

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, vbo, vao

I am freaking out to solve my software flickering while running/processing images.

First, I'll introduce my problem, explaining what I did, then at the end I'll leave my questions/needs:

My software process images and shows it imediatelly on screen, acting like a scanner. The image pixels is built using image photosensors, processed using OpenCV, and draw as soon as possible on screen to provide a smooth movement while the image is generated.

In practice, I first have a white-solid 1000x808 blank image, which its pixels are replaced with respective photosensored built-image and is show on the screen so that the image flows from the left to the right on the screen.
The entire process of each frame generation lasts about 10 ~ 12ms.

However, The frames does not flows as expected on screen. It flickers a lot. As I have no Idea how to measure FPS on OpenGL, I suppose my OpenGL code (which I know nothing about OpenGL at all) is causing the flickering.

I am using the following code on my GLWidget, which I did my best to write but I am quite sure that it is not OpenGL best-performance-written.

I have almost nothing on my GLWidget constructor, but I have playing around with these functions, with no significant effect:

```
 QGLFormat glFormat;
    glFormat.setSwapInterval(0);
    glFormat.setDoubleBuffer(true);
    glFormat.setSampleBuffers(true);
    glFormat.setDirectRendering(true);
    glFormat.setSamples(4);
    setFormat(glFormat);
```

My initializeGL is shown as follows:

```
initializeGL()
{    
    glClearColor(255.0f,255.0f,255.0f,0.1f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,this->width(), this->height(), 0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(3, &this->texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, this->width(), this->height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    this->original = cv::Mat(this->height(), this->width(), CV_8UC4);
    memset(this->original.data, 0xff, this->original.rows * this->original.step);

    this->repaint = true;
}
```

As you can see, at this point a blank image sized 1000x808 (screen size) is shown on initialization (because images aren't built yet)

When the images starts to being built (every 5 column) I send the image (through setImage) to the screen, then it renders with OpenGL on overriden paintGL function:

```
setImage(cv::Mat imageRGBA)
{
    this->original = imageRGBA;
    this->repaint = true;
    update();
}
paintGL()
{
    if (this->repaint) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, this->original.cols, this->original.rows, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this->original.data );

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(0,this->height());
        glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(0,0);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(this->width(),0);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(this->width(),this->height());
        glEnd();

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        this->repaint = false;
    }
}
```

**Considerations:**
As you can see, I work only with 2D images sized 1000x808 (fixed), and it shouldn't require too much power for rendering. I am currently coding this to work on Intel Core i3 Haswell machine (with integrated intel HD Graphics). On top a Linux Ubuntu 14.04 x64 OS, with latest intel drivers installed.

**Expectation:**
I expect to render/draw the images as soon as possible, without flickering. I have about 150 1000x808 images to render in a row (with ~12ms between images build process).
I would love to have a smooth ~60Hz smooth images being rendered on the screen

**Questions:**

- Based on my code, what I need to do due to improve performance and stop flickering?
- Is it really necessary to move to QOpenGLWidget other than current QGLWidget (deprecated?)?
- As I have been written an OpenGL "immediate mode" code, Should I consider to move to VBO/PBO/VAO? And which one is best suitable for me?
- Do I need linux tweaks due to improve performance? If so, what kind
  of?
- Any kind of help is very welcome!

Comment: Flickering is not a performance issue, it's a bug in your program. You're requesting a double-buffered context (`glFormat.setDoubleBuffer(true);`) but I don't see any place where you're swapping buffers.

Comment: Also, please only ask one question per question.

Comment: You don't even need OpenGL for this, you could simply paint a `QImage` on a custom widget, and it'd be fast enough.

Comment: @KubaOber, I could if I wouldn't bother about software rendering, neither CPU performance. However, performance is very need on this software, though. So, Hardware render acceleration is mandatory for me to decrease CPU usage.

My early versions used to be like that, drawing on QLabel with QPixmap, also tried QImage... But realtime is very important here

Comment: I agree, but let's note that going through a pixmap is a long route around. Instead, drawing an opaque `QImage` on a `QWidget` using `drawImage` amounts to a striped `memcpy` into a texture anyway - whether you're on OS X, Windows, or local X11. Most CPUs won't even notice it happening, you can `memcpy` tens of gigabytes per second.